# ISPConfig installation doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

My ISPConfig 3 setup (3.0.4.6) is behaving strange. First I get a load of

```
sh: 1: /which: not found
sh: 1: /which: not found
sh: 1: /which: not found
sh: 1: /which: not found
sh: 1: /which: not found
sh: 1: /which: not found
...
```

messages (which I ignored) and then after entering my MySQL data I get

```
sh: 1: /mysql: not found
sh: 1: /echo: not found
ERROR: Unable to load SQL-Dump into database table.
```

Funny thing is... which, mysql and echo commands are of course available from the command line (server has a standard LAMP setup).

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, could have thought of that. The standard setup also includes "SafeMode = ON" even for CLI PHP. Stupid that the error message was not about that in any way...